# Compare multiple lists with the output being the number and identity of each missmatch between every pair of lists

Tags: python, list, compare

I am trying to compare multiple lists:

```
list1 = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...]
list2 = ['A', 'B', 'X', ...]
list3 = ['A', 'X', 'C', ...]
```

The output should give me for each pair of lists the identity and nature of each mismatch. E.g.:

```
Comp_list1_list2 = C,X and pos3
Comp_list1_list3 = B,X and pos2
Comp_list2_list3 = B,X; X,C and pos2; pos3
```

I realize this might be a difficult problem and that it has to be broken down into smaller bits. Any hints to get me on the right track will be very much appreciated!

Comment: Which programming language is this? Please [post your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Also, could you please explain *why* you are trying to do this? It sounds like this might be an example of the [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

Comment: This is almost looking like a `diff` algorithm. You might want to do a little Googling on that...

Comment: Hi guys. I am doing prgramming in python - and I am fairly new to it. But after a long day trying I solved my problem. It is probaly not the most elegant solution, but it does work!!;))

Comment: Since you are now looking for  feedback on the code that already works, [codereview.se] is the appropriate site to ask at.

Comment: You can add an answer and accept it in order to mark this question as *resolved*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem myself - not the most elegant solution, but it works anyway...

```
from xlrd import *
def main():
    '''This Program reads input (A:clone name, B:sequence, C:elisa) from an
    Excel file and makes a cross comparison of each sequence pair'''
    book = open_workbook("mtask.xlsx")
    Input = book.sheet_by_index(0)

# naming of input data
a = (Input.col_values(0,0))
b = (Input.col_values(1,0))
c = (Input.col_values(2,0))

# make dictionary: keys are seq numbers; values are residues 
y = {}
for i in range(Input.nrows):
    x = []
    for j in b[i]:
        x.append(j)
    y[a[i]] = x

# comparison of sequences and extraction of mutations for each sequence pair
List = []
for shit in range(Input.nrows):
    for seq in range(Input.nrows):
        seq12 = []
        z = 0
        for i in y[a[seq]]:
            try:
                for j in y[a[shit]][z]:
                     if i == j:
                         seq12.append(i.lower()+j.lower())
                     else:
                         seq12.append(i+j)
                z = z+1
            except IndexError:
                 print("oops")

        lib = [a[seq],a[shit],c[seq],c[shit]]
        for position, item in enumerate(seq12):
            if item.isupper():
                x = (str(item[0])+str(position+1)+str(item[1]))
                lib.append(x)
        List.append(lib)

# comparison of sequences and extraction of mutations for each sequence pair
dic = {}
for i in range(Input.nrows*Input.nrows):
    x = []
    for j in List[i]:
        x.append(j)
    dic[i] = x

# sort
a = []
for i in dic.values():
    a.append(i)

# collect number of mutations in data files
import csv
null = []
one = []
two = []
three = []
four = []
five = []
six = []
seven = []
eight = []
nine = []
ten = []
for i in range(Input.nrows*Input.nrows):
    if len(a[i]) <= 4:
        null.append(a[i])
        with open("no_mut.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(null)
    elif len(a[i]) == 5:
        one.append(a[i])
        with open("one.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(one)
    elif len(a[i]) == 6:
        two.append(a[i])
        with open("two.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(two)
    elif len(a[i]) == 7:
        three.append(a[i])
        with open("three.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(three)
    elif len(a[i]) == 8:
        four.append(a[i])
        with open("four.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(four)
    elif len(a[i]) == 9:
        five.append(a[i])
        with open("five.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(five)
    elif len(a[i]) == 10:
        six.append(a[i])
        with open("six.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(six)
    elif len(a[i]) == 11:
        seven.append(a[i])
        with open("seven.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(seven)
    elif len(a[i]) == 12:
        eight.append(a[i])
        with open("eight.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(eight)
    elif len(a[i]) == 13:
        nine.append(a[i])
        with open("nine.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(nine)
    elif len(a[i]) == 14:
        ten.append(a[i])
        with open("ten.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(ten)

main()
```